# Trouble aligning labels, input in a form

Tags: html, css

Hello i'm having trouble aligning labels, input field and drop box in my html page. I want the labels aligned at the left and input right next to it. But it's allover the place and having trouble aligning it. I would like my form to look like this

[image]

But my page currently looks like this:
[image]

Below is my html and css code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
  <meta name="description" content="Assignment 3 using Ajax" />

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Assignment 3</title>

 <!--CSS Styling -->
 <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <!-- script -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
 </script>

</head>

<body>
  <header><h1> Registration </h1></header>
    <form name="myForm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="username">Username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="user" placeholder="Enter username" />

            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="user_p" />

            <progress id="progress" value='0' max="100"></progress><span id="text"></span>

            <label for="re_password">Verify Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="re_password" name="user_pass" placeholder="Re-enter password" />

            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter email"  />

            <label for="email">Verify Email: </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email2" />    

            <label for="question1">Security Question </label>
            <select id="question1" name="question1">
                <option value="none"> --- Select a question --- </option>
                <option value="a">What's your favorite color?</option>
                <option value="b">What's the make of your first car?</option>
                <option value="c">What's your mother's maiden name?</option>
                <option value="d">What city were you born?</option>
                <option value="e">What high school did you attend?</option>
            </select>

            <label for="answer">Security Answer: </label>
            <input type="text" name="user_answer1"  />

            <label for="question2">Security Question </label>
            <select id="question2" name="question2">
                <option value="none"> --- Select a question --- </option>
                <option value="a">What's your favorite color?</option>
                <option value="b">What's the make of your first car?</option>
                <option value="c">What's your mother's maiden name?</option>
                <option value="d">What city were you born?</option>
                <option value="e">What high school did you attend?</option>
            </select>


            <label for="answer2"> Security Answer: </label>
            <input type="text" id="answer2" name="user_answer2" />

            <label for="mobile">Phone: </label>
            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="user_mobile" />

            <label for="address">Address: </label>
            <textarea id="t1" rows="8" cols="40"name="user_address" style="vertical-align: top;"></textarea>

            <label for="interests">Areas you may be interested in, please select one or more: </label>
            <textarea id="interests" rows="10" cols="40" name="user_extra" style="vertical-align: top;"></textarea>

            <div id="box1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <img src="Red_Apple.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="110" height="40" />
            </div>
            <div id="box2"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <img src="Banana.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="110" height="40" />
            </div>

            <div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>            
        </fieldset>

        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="return validate()" />
        <input type="button" value="Clear" />

    </form>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
form {
     max-width: 750px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     background: #f4f7f8;
     border-radius: 8px;
    }
label {
     display:block;
     text-align: right;
     width:145px;
     float: left;
     padding-top: 5px;
   }

input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }

fieldset  {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
   }

#box1, #box2 {
    float:right;
    width: 112px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }

div#box3{
  width:112px;
  height:42px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
```

Please could some lead me in the right directions of how to currently aligning the labels and input like in the first pic.

Comment: Is it possible to use bootstrap?

Comment: @rsabir no bootstrap for this exercise

Comment: The problem you face is how 'float' work. You currently only apply it on the label so that makes them all stack up while the input is not floated. Just a hint for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put each 'line' of `input` and `label` inside a wrapper `div`, you can easily solve the problems you're getting. The wrapper acts like a full width wrapper around the label and input of that row. Every new label & input will go onto the next line.

I also did some adjustments to your `label` styling, as it needs to be `display: inline-block;` and no `float: left;` is needed.

See [my JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zjt9bnhx/).

Comment: i thought about the idea but wasn't sure if it was the right way

Comment: if i wanted the drop box to float to the right of the address label right after the text area. how do i go about that

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald Give them all an extra class and set `label, `textarea` `dropbox` to `float: left;` Try playing around with it, we're here to help, but not to do your homework.

Comment: thanks for the help. No problem you have been of great help

Answer (score 0):

I know that you want a native css solution but I've done a bootstrap version for fun. You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pntxa31o/).

The equivalent of my solution would be to make specific width for label and input :

```
input,label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:60%;
}
label{
  width:30%;
}
```

And make sure that the sum will be 100% or use container div as I do in [bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/pntxa31o/).